# trigger.io remove all files stored with forge.file.SaveURL?

Tags: file, save, trigger.io

I make extensive use of the file.saveURL feature of trigger.io but I would like to know if its possible or maybe possible to add this functionality but to run a command to remove all stored items?

The app I am creating is customizable by the user and because of that they have the ability to "leave" the app in a since.

Doing so will clear out all localstorage and any downloaded items.

Currently I have a method that stores each reference in a localstorage and when I "leave" I loop over the items in the LC and remove each item. While this seems to work ok it does have querks at times. I'm just curious if it may be possible to add a simple remove all  type function to the file save?

Seeing as we are responsible to the cleanup of these items it would be nice to simply remove all stored items

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no - we don't save those files in a separate folder, which could have been cleared up in one go...

It's a change we could make in the future though if it proves a popular update to the file module!

Comment: Hi James, I know in Android everything is stored in the trigger.io directory is this not the case for IOS as well? I would think the files would have to be stored in the context of the app right?

Comment: Yep - on iOS, we store saveURL files in the application support directory: what I mean is they're not in some designated sub-directory there, that a "clear all" API could safely delete...